# Dynamic Where clause with unknown number of parameters

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, dynamic, linq-to-entities

I have searched for an answer to my question, but have been unable to find one that meets my needs.

The following two code snippets return the same thing and I have no preference which one to use, I am just including both in case it helps someone answer my question

```
private List<MyClass> GetMyClass(string name, string city, string state, string zip)
{
    using (MyEntities ctx = new MyEntities())
    {
        var results = from a in ctx.MyEntity
                      where (a.Name == name &&
                             a.City == city &&
                             a.State == state &&
                             a.ZIP == zip)
                      select a;

        return results.ToList();
    }
}

private List<MyClass> GetMyClass(string name, string city, string state, string zip)
{
    using (MyEntities ctx = new MyEntities())
    {
        var results = ctx.MyEntity.Where(a => a.Name == name)
                                  .Where(a => a.City == city)
                                  .Where(a => a.State == state)
                                  .Where(a => a.ZIP == zip)
                                  .Select(a => a);

        return results.ToList();
    }
}
```

For the purposes of this example, let's say I have a search screen which requires users to enter a Name and a City; State and ZIP are optional.  The query must at least search by those two fields, and any additional fields, if necessary.

Obviously, with my above examples, if a user searches only by Name and City, they would not get any results as the queries would be trying to match State == null and ZIP == null since those two parameters where not supplied.

How can I rewrite this code to only search on the fields that parameters have been supplied for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just chain them, something like:

```
var results = ctx.MyEntity.AsQueryable();

if(name != null)
    results = results.Where(a => a.Name == name);

// ... snip ...

if(zip != null)
    results = results.Where(a => a.ZIP == zip)

return results.ToList();
```

Comment: `results` needs to be of type `IQueryable<T>`, not of a more derived type, for this to compile.  Trivial change though.

Answer (score 2):

```
var results = from a in ctx.MyEntity
              where ((a.Name == name || name == null) &&
                     (a.City == city || city == null) &&
                     (a.State == state || state == null) &&
                     (a.ZIP == zip) || zip == null)
              select a;
```